# openGl glGetUniformLocation returns -1

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

**it's always returns -1 , here is the code

**simple_fragment_shader**

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 v_Color;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = v_Color;
}
```

**simple_vertex_shader**

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_Color;
varying vec4 v_Color;
void main()
{
    v_Color = a_Color;
    gl_Position = a_Position;
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}
```

why `aColorLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, A_COLOR)` retuns -1

where `private val A_COLOR = "a_Color"`

and `program = 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a_Color` is an attribute. Either make it a uniform or use `glGetAttribLocation`.